# WooCommerce php 8.1 + WordPress 5.7.2

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, compatibility

I have an issue with using new PHP 8.1 on WordPress 5.7.2. Everything work just fine, until turn on WooCommerce 5.3.0. Then whole site fall down.

Here is error message what I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function putenv() in
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-regenerate-images-request.php:37
> Stack trace: #0
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-regenerate-images.php(49):
> WC_Regenerate_Images_Request->__construct() #1
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292):
> WC_Regenerate_Images::init('') #2
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-includes/plugin.php(484):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-settings.php(560):
> do_action('init') #5
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-config.php(90):
> require_once('/data/web/virtu...') #6
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-load.php(37):
> require_once('/data/web/virtu...') #7
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-admin/admin.php(34):
> require_once('/data/web/virtu...') #8
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-admin/plugins.php(10):
> require_once('/data/web/virtu...') #9 {main} thrown in
> /data/web/virtuals/2036/virtual/www/domains/e-biowa.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-regenerate-images-request.php
> on line 37

Please does anyone know, if there is any problem with compatibility? I didn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a problem with 8.1 over 8.0.

PHP has a function blacklist.

Remove `putenv` from the blacklist. This worked for me when I received this error using PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is not ready yet for PHP 8.1. If you install on 8.1 you can show dozens of errors about deprecated methods like ltrim() or count, even if install WordPress 5.8.2. You can fix most of the issues in this [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQbaDBDCOIA)
but its not worth that. My advice is you wait for the compatible version of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or change this lines from php ini or config file:
//either put colon or remove this whole line

;disable_functions = passthru,exec,putenv,system,chroot,chgrp,chown,shell_exec,popen,proc_open,pcntl_exec,ini_alter,ini_restore,dl,openlog,syslog,readlink,symlink,popepassthru,pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,imap_open,apache_setenv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).